# How do I switch tabs in Google Chrome without a mouse?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I switch tabs in Google Chrome without a mouse?

Much like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change between windows.

Comment: I was tempted to answer "the same way as everywhere else" ...

Comment: You could always use a track-ball

Comment: option + command + arrow keys?

Comment: Such shortcut does not exist for Chrome but there are many extensions which try doing this. Here's one CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

This works in most MDI interface style applications as well.

Comment: Bam! That one was answer bait.

Comment: the first goes to the next tab,the second chooses the previous one

Comment: @op Another useful key combo is `Ctrl+w`, which closes the currently active tab and activates the next tab to the left.  I often prefer that to `ctrl+shift+tab`, but I use them both.  You can also use `ctrl+1-9`, which gives you tabs 1-9 (sometimes 9 references final, I think).

Answer (score 10):

You can also <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch to the first tab, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to switch to the second, and so on.

Comment: Yes, also works in Windows with Ctrl.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> also work (on Windows).

Comment: Works on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted this feature myself, I have tried most existing extensions already available but none of them worked properly.

I went ahead and tried my hand at developing one myself and it seems to be working for me. Figured it might help others too.

Here is the link: [CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn)

Answer (score 0):

A great way to jump to a specific tab is the new [**Switch to Tab Extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbfhhcljihbgcobpfnceegfmooomhhli#).

Install the extension, jump to address bar (<kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), type `SW` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type your search term (e.g. `mail`), press enter to switch to the first result.